# How to set a new baseline heart rate?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

When first starting the adventure mode, it takes several base readings of your body. One of which, it seems, is the heart rate that it later bases calorie calculations and post-course heartrate measurements on. However, I've been using this software for three months now and see no way to update these (hopefully) now out of date numbers.

Does it somehow do it automatically, or am I missing the option somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot find any evidence that the game uses your initial heart rate measurement for calorie calculations or post-course measurements.**

The [first time Ring Fit Adventure measures your heart rate](https://youtu.be/ASOe_9idvpY?t=820) happens after initial calibration when you Sync with Ring by holding your thumb against the heart rate sensor. The game does not mention anything about your heart rate being saved or recorded for calorie calculations.

[image: Initial heart rate measurement]
<sub>Screenshot from [XCageGame - Ring Fit Adventure Gameplay Walkthrough Part 1 - World 1 (14:00)](https://youtu.be/ASOe_9idvpY?t=820)</sub>

It's worth noting that the game *does* use your age and weight from your initial calibration to estimate stamina and calories respectively.

[image: Weight used for calorie calculations]
<sub>Screenshot from [XCageGame - Ring Fit Adventure Gameplay Walkthrough Part 1 - World 1 (5:46)](https://youtu.be/ASOe_9idvpY?t=346)</sub>

[According to Nintendo Support](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-Switch/How-to-Adjust-Profile-Settings-and-Options-Ring-Fit-Adventure--1664665.html), you can adjust your age and weight by pressing B on the right Joy-Con while playing a game mode then selecting "Settings:.